# API to add users to an iTunes Connect account

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I’ve come across a service that allows you to add your iTunes Connect credentials, and through some API or ??? it generates a user on their behalf on your iTunes Connect account.

It actually works and automatically creates a user with the roles of reports, sales, and technical.

I tried looking through the iTunes Connect docs for some guidance on how to do this but I can’t seem to find how this is done.  Would appreciate any thoughts.

The site is Fliptopia and [this is the link to the sync page](https://www.fliptopia.com/external_accounts/itunes_connect) but you have to create an account and login to see it.  So if you don’t want to create an account, I’ve posted a screen shot for your reference.

Additionally, I’d like to find a way to automate the invitation of a user to an Apple developer account as well incase someone happens to know to know of a way to do that.  Haven’t seen any examples though.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't quite have the functionality that you're looking for (I think), but `spaceship` is a tool to interface with iTC and the dev portal: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship

I think it only supports adding Testers rather than full users.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an API. You're giving your Apple ID username and password to this service. *This lets them log in and perform actions as you,* including adding users to your team (as well as anything else they want).

Giving your Apple ID password to another site, or using someone else's username and password (as this site is doing!) is a violation of the iTunes Connect Terms of Service:

> **Account and Password.** As a registered user of iTunes Connect, you must establish an account ("Account"). You are solely responsible for maintaining the confidentiality and security of your Account. You may not reveal your Account information to anyone else, allow anyone else to use your Account, or use anyone else's Account.

So I wouldn't recommend it. If you want users to add you to their iTunes Connect account, give them instructions on how to do it manually.